# How do extract domain extension of the elements in python list without using any build in function?

Tags: python, list, dns

Consider my list is:

`my_list=["www.annauniv.edu","www.facebook.com"]`

My expected output should be:

```
Domain extension of the elements in list are: ['.edu','.com']
```

**MY CODING:**

```
my_list=["www.annauniv.edu","www.tneaonline.org","www.facebook.com"]
print(my_list)
s=[]
for i in my_list:
    s.append(i[-3:])
print(s)
```

Is there any simpler coding for this?

Comment: `"a.b.c".rsplit(".", 1)` returns `("a.b", "c")`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Tanq. But i need that, without using rsplit() or any other build in functions in that program.

Comment: You should try something first

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I've tried the above one.

Comment: wont work for longer than `.com`  what if domain is `example.info` with some effort you can get by yourself

Comment: This is not possible to do in all generality, without either doing DNS queries or using the Public Suffix List. You can not find the suffix just by looking at the string. `dk` is a valid domain, and host, and suffix. In `www.minefi.gouv.fr` the suffix is `gouv.fr` (but it is not delegated). In `example.com` the suffix is `com` but in `example.br.com` the suffix is `br.com`. Etc.

Comment: Please do not say "extension". You either have a TLD, or a domain, or a suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it makes any sense not

```
my_list=["www.annauniv.edu","www.facebook.com"]

res = []
for el in my_list:
    for ind, let in enumerate(el[-1:0:-1]):
        if let == '.':
            res.append(el[-ind-1:])
            break
res
```

output:

```
['.edu', '.com']
```

P.S. your solution will crash if domain will have 2 letters: `.en` for example

Comment: I think iterating the whole string is not a good idea can be shorter than this and there is a `.` after www too :)

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Look carefully - I'm iterating from end to first `.`. Will no iterate over all the string

Comment: Oh yes i see `[-1:0:-1]` reversing the string I think whole could be more readable or simpler than reversing getting index by enumerate and finding the first `.` then 
 starting from **index-1** appending to result and breaking the loop :D and OP here is taking python lessons

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam you gave me the exact solution for my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) doesn't count as a built-in function?

Comment: @Matthias we can easily replace `enumerate` with counter and count++ in the loop :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
list(map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1], my_list))
```

For getting the domain extension, you split each string by `.`'s and take the last element which is done with `x.split[-1]`. Then you do it for all elements in the list

Comment: i've tried your coding and got the following as output . . . .  ['edu', 'com', 'in', 'info'].      
It gets the word from index no. -1 to  '' . " .

Comment: What is your exact input?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=["www.annauniv.edu","www.tneaonline.org","www.facebook.com"]
print(my_list)
s = [i[-3:] for i in my_list]
print(s)
```

This will helps : )

Comment: Tanq.I too tried the same way without using list comprehensive. But the problem here is, suppose if we have different size of domain name in list elements means it won't be work.